# Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: Delivery is not allowed to this address

Tags: c#, smtp

I have recently transferred providers for my app and now get the following error when the app tries to send mail

> Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: Delivery is not allowed to this address.

Ive tried various different email addresses and also their technical support who are proving to be not that helpful.

It is an asp.net mvc app and the controller code is:

```
        public ActionResult EmailEventRegister(int eventId)
    {
        //Find Event
        var eventSel = db.Events.FirstOrDefault(t => t.EventId == eventId);

        MailMessage enteredMessage = new MailMessage();
        enteredMessage.Subject = "YFA Event Attendance Details for " + eventSel.Name + " " + eventSel.EventDate.ToLongDateString();
        enteredMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
        var bodyBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        bodyBuilder.AppendLine(branch.BranchName + " YFA are attending the following event: " +
              "<br />" +
              "<br />Event: " + eventSel.Name +
              "<br />");

        enteredMessage.Body = bodyBuilder.ToString();
        enteredMessage.From = new MailAddress("phillsanders@me.com", "Droitwich YFA");

        enteredMessage.CC.Add("phillsanders@me.com");

        enteredMessage.To.Add(new MailAddress("phillsanders@me.com"));
        SmtpClient mySmtpClient = new SmtpClient("icebreak.host4asp.net");

        NetworkCredential Credentials = new NetworkCredential("contact@yfainfo.com", "Passwordhere");
        mySmtpClient.Credentials = Credentials;
        mySmtpClient.Send(enteredMessage);

        mySmtpClient.Send(enteredMessage);

        var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        var branchId = db.Instructors.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ApplicationUserId == userId).BranchId;

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Events", new { branchId = branchId});
    }
```

Comment: Why did you tag that asp.net? The error is server side and would be exactly the same in a winform or console application.

Comment: The error indicates this is a problem on the mail server.  Are you *absolutely* certain the email address is correct and exists on the mail server, and that it can receive email?  The inbox could be full, for instance.

Comment: Thanks Amy, yes I've tried several emails and it's the same as previously used I'm seem to be struggling to persuade the provider that's it a server issue I've also tried another smtp provider and it works fine

Comment: I doubt this is something we can help with.